# Question about the effect of a parameter of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, parametric

I was given this question, and I'm not really sure how to answer it

Consider the function $f(x)=-x^2\arcsin(ax-1)+2\pi$ where *a* is an element of the positive real numbers

Determine the value of *a* such that when $f(x)=7$, the difference between the corresponding *x*-values is 3 (correct to 3 d.p)

I've tried to use the transformations when $a=1$ but I still haven't found the answer, when I graph it in Desmos I can find the answer, but I was asking to see if I could find the answer algebraically

Thanks!

Comment: System of equations $f(x)=7, f(x+3)=7$ leads to trancendental equation, so there is no algebraic solution.

Comment: There are two $a$ values with the same absolute value